# How to create a grid from three mysql tables

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I am trying to create a grid with yii using three different tables. Here is a rough demonstration of what I am trying to achieve:

```
Table: Products
prod_id, prod_name

Table: Regions
reg_id, reg_name

Table: Prices
price_id, prod_id, reg_id, price


Products/Regions | Region#1 | Region#2 | ... | Region#N
--------------------------------------------------------
Product#1        | Price#1  | Price#2  | ... | Price#N
Product#2        | Price#1  | Price#2  | ... | Price#N
Product#3        | Price#1  | Price#2  | ... | Price#N
...
Product#N        | Price#1  | Price#2  | ... | Price#N
```

I need to approach this from the products table. I need to be able to search the products. And I don't need to to use GridView, also it would be optimal if I can use it.

I really need recommendation more than anything in this situation. One idea I have is to create a double array of prices and access them and put them in the table `$prices[$prod_id][$reg_id]` but this system has to be really optimal and performance plays a huge role. So, I would appreciate if anyone can help me out with this.

Thanks,
Gasim

Comment: you should be able to do this using relational rules which will allow you to combine all the tables: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.arr

Comment: best choice here is to create cdatacolumns and populate CGridView with them. `<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array( 'columns'=>$columns`